# Anyone know the Android APP auto touch?Who can help me simulate the touch event in Android

Tags: android

I want to develop an android APP ,it can touch some app already existed(like FaceBook,Clash of Clans).Now I am meeting an question:my app could not get the View of another app which is running.
The code are as fllows：

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable= new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v_currentView=getWindow().getDecorView();
        //View v_currentView=View.inflate(this, com.tencent.mm.R, root);
        click(v_currentView, x, y);
    }
};
public void click(final View view, final int x, final int y) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // SIMULATION BEGINS HERE AFTER 2000 Millis ///
                long touchTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                simulationEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(touchTime, touchTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
                view.dispatchTouchEvent(simulationEvent);

                simulationEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(touchTime, touchTime,
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
                view.dispatchTouchEvent(simulationEvent);
                Log.e("simulatedTouch","simulated touch executed at X:"+x+" Y:"+y);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Firstly, I open the FaceBook that I want to touch autoly. Secondly,I use the 'Click' function simulating touch screen.But the FaceBook responsed nothing.If I need some special permissions or not?

Comment: You can't, purposely.  Its to prevent malware.  And you couldn't get a view in another app if you wanted-  they run in separate processes.

Comment: But why the [Auto Touch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro&hl=en) can reslize the function?

Comment: Requires root-  probably running directly on the driver level.

Comment: Thank you very much.I know very less about driver level.Do you have some suggestions about start learning to developing driver program on Android.

Comment: I think AutoTouch is basically used for JUnit testing of code.

Comment: Thank you,I don't want to do JUnit testing of code.I want to realize this function in my app.